# Extract all H.264 NALUs specific to a frame for a P-Frame using command line

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I want to use ffmpeg to extract frame data from command line, similar to what you would get by calling av_send_frame and then calling av_receive_packet (until EOF / Error). I want to extract the full data (NALUs) of single arbitrary frames without decoding or re-encoding them. (i.e. I expect extracted P-frames to be very small and not reconstructed from their reference frames)

I know I can code a tiny tool for doing this, but I suspect this functionality may be already exposed through a bitstream filter in the command line. Is that the case?

Comment: what do you mean by "data", Like pixels? or nalus?

Comment: `av_read_frame`, contrary to its name, returns packets, not frames, so NALUs. This is possible via the segment muxer but make sure to enable splitting on non keyframes.

Comment: I meant NALUs, sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: @Gyan Thanks, I updated the question. I was looking for something more precise that would allow me to get single frames, but yeah the segment/ssegment muxers are similar to what I need.

Comment: So via CLI, it would be segment muxer with input seek `-ss pframe-ts` and output `-c copy -copyts -to pframe-ts`

Comment: So for a single frame, wouldn't that be (at 60fps)
ffmpeg -i source.h264 -f segment -ss 0:00.16 -c copy -copyts-to 0:00.33 pframe.h264 ?
For an raw stream (no container) I assume I should pass the fps as well